# Scaling Heroku using a scheduled task

Tags: python, heroku, scaling, autoscaling

I have a python heroku app with a very predictable, but varying load.

What I want to do is run a scheduled task every 10 min and scale according to some metrics I get from the database.

I can use the platform api, but the authentication part baffles me. How do I get token/authenticate if I am running a process on a dyno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTTP basic authentication and an [API token](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication). You can retrieve your token by using `heroku auth:token` on the command line or in your account settings on Heroku's website.

You need to include it in the `Authorization` header with requests to the Platform API. See [this article for instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart#authentication)